# In Spring, Is There A Way to Render A Swagger Doc From A YAML File

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

In the spring framework, the common pattern seems to be to generate a swagger doc from controller annotations. Our swagger.yaml file is running our validation on incoming requests so we want to render the swagger doc from the yaml file in the resources folder; and we want to avoid having so many annotations in our controllers. Is there a way to do this in Spring?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Take a look at open api maven plugin https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin
With him you can generate classes with swagger annotations from swagger.yaml file.
I dont know the way not to use the annotations for swagger.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely don't want to generate classes/annotations from swagger files